# Load data dynamically while scrolling

Tags: ios, dynamic, scroll, plist

I am working on an application where i scroll many images that are loaded from a plist. Currently I loop through the contents of a plist and load all of them at once in viewDidiLoad, but i need only one to show up on the screen, and have the next one in memory in order to scroll. Could anyone advise what would be a good way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: What sort of control are you using? TableView, PageViewController, ScrollView?  Or is it a custom view that you have created?

Comment: I am adding images to scrollview. ATM I calculate the height of all content and put them all in a ScrollView and enable paging.

Comment: OK, you can make paging work in a better way.  When paging you only need the current image, the previous image and the next image loaded.